# Transferring the form from one place to another

Tags: javascript, html

Good day,
I need help to switch the form to a popout that pops up when the button is clicked

I have this right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU6UF.png

But i want this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShsvP.png

I was able to achieve this by changing the code to take the value from the document, but then take it only from the first form and the other forms are the same for other products, and I don't want that.

This is error when i have portfolioItem down: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')

Here is my code:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("take")) {
    togglePortfolioPopup();
    document.querySelector(".portfolio-popup").scrollTo(0, 0);
    portfolioItemDetails(e.target.parentElement);
  }
})

function togglePortfolioPopup() {
  document.querySelector(".portfolio-popup").classList.toggle("open");
  document.body.classList.toggle("hide-scrolling");
}

// Hide popup when click outside of it
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("pp-inner")) {
    togglePortfolioPopup();
  }
});

function portfolioItemDetails(portfolioItem) {
  document.querySelector(".pp-header h3").innerHTML = portfolioItem.querySelector(".naziv").innerHTML;
  document.querySelector(".pp-header p").innerHTML = portfolioItem.querySelector(".poeni").innerHTML;
  document.querySelector(".pp-body").innerHTML = portfolioItem.querySelector(".portfolio-item-details").innerHTML;
};
```

```html
<h2 class="naziv">Bs battle pass</h2>
<span class="poeni">17,000 poena</span>

<!-- This is one card-->
<div class="shopbox">
  <div class="card" id="card1">
    <div class="novo">NOVO!</div>
    <div class="stanje1">Na stanju: <span style="color: gold">2</span></div>
    <div class="imgBx">
      <img src="images/Produkti/battlepass.png">
    </div>
    <div class="contentBx">
      <h2 class="naziv">Bs battle pass</h2>
      <span class="snizenje">18,000 poena</span>
      <span class="poeni">17,000 poena</span>
      <button class="take">Uzmi sada</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- This is form -->
  <div class="portfolio-item-details">
    <section id="porudzbine">

      <form action="https://formsubmit.co/shop@tutz.info" method="POST">
        <div class="form-row">

          <div class="input-data">
            <input type="text" name="Ime i Prezime" required>
            <div class="underline"></div>
            <label>Ime i Prezime</label>
          </div>

          <div class="input-data">
            <input type="email" name="Email" required>
            <div class="underline"></div>
            <label>Email adresa</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="input-data">
            <input type="text" name="Ime u igrici" required>
            <div class="underline"></div>
            <label>Brawl stars username</label>
          </div>

          <div class="input-data">
            <input type="text" name="TIktok username" required>
            <div class="underline"></div>
            <label>Tiktok username</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="input-data textarea">
            <textarea rows="8" cols="80" name="Poruka" required></textarea>
            <br>
            <div class="underline"></div>
            <label>Zasto kupujes ovaj proizvod iz shopa?</label>
            <h6>>Ukoliko ti je potrebna pomoc mozes da nam pises na:
              <a href="mailto: shop@tutz.info" target="_blank">shop@tutz.info</a></h6>

            <div class="form-row submit-btn">
              <div class="input-data">
                <div class="inner"></div>
                <input type="submit" value="Posalji">
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="Nova porudzbina: battlepass!">
            <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://tutz.info/hvala.html">
            <input type="hidden" name="_template" value="table">
            <input type="hidden" name="_blacklist" value="spammy pattern, banned term, phrase">

          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- This is popout where value need to implement -->

<div class="portfolio-popup">
  <div class="pp-inner">
    <div class="pp-content">

      <div class="pp-header">
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
        <p style="color: red; text-align: center; font-weight: 700">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-triangle-exclamation fa-beat-fade" style="color:red"></i> Slanje forme bez dovoljno poena ce biti kaznjeno smanjenjem poena
          <i class="fa-solid fa-triangle-exclamation fa-beat-fade" style="color:red"></i>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="pp-body">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you calling the function? The error indicates that `<div class="portfolio-item-details">` doesn't exist. Could you be calling the function before that's added to the DOM?

Comment: Note that copying the HTML of the element will create a duplicate `<section id="porudzbine">`. IDs are supposed to be unique.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error when I add a call `portfolioItemDetails(document);`

Comment: I changed the code to include the card as well as the rest of the javascript code. Maybe that will help

Answer (score 0):

`portfolioItem` is `<div class="contentBx">`. The `.portfolio-item-details` div is not inside that, so it won't be found with `portfolioItemDetails.querySelector()`. You need to pass a larger container to `portfolioItemDetails()`. The common container is `<div class="shopbox">`.

You can use `e.target.closest(".shopbox")` to get this element.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("take")) {
    togglePortfolioPopup();
    document.querySelector(".portfolio-popup").scrollTo(0, 0);
    portfolioItemDetails(e.target.closest(".shopbox"));
  }
})

function togglePortfolioPopup() {
  document.querySelector(".portfolio-popup").classList.toggle("open");
  document.body.classList.toggle("hide-scrolling");
}

// Hide popup when click outside of it
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("pp-inner")) {
    togglePortfolioPopup();
  }
});

function portfolioItemDetails(portfolioItem) {
  document.querySelector(".pp-header h3").innerHTML = portfolioItem.querySelector(".naziv").innerHTML;
  document.querySelector(".pp-header p").innerHTML = portfolioItem.querySelector(".poeni").innerHTML;
  document.querySelector(".pp-body").innerHTML = portfolioItem.querySelector(".portfolio-item-details").innerHTML;
};
```

```html
<h2 class="naziv">Bs battle pass</h2>
<span class="poeni">17,000 poena</span>

<!-- This is one card-->
<div class="shopbox">
  <div class="card" id="card1">
    <div class="novo">NOVO!</div>
    <div class="stanje1">Na stanju: <span style="color: gold">2</span></div>
    <div class="imgBx">
      <img src="images/Produkti/battlepass.png">
    </div>
    <div class="contentBx">
      <h2 class="naziv">Bs battle pass</h2>
      <span class="snizenje">18,000 poena</span>
      <span class="poeni">17,000 poena</span>
      <button class="take">Uzmi sada</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- This is form -->
  <div class="portfolio-item-details">
    <section id="porudzbine">

      <form action="https://formsubmit.co/shop@tutz.info" method="POST">
        <div class="form-row">

          <div class="input-data">
            <input type="text" name="Ime i Prezime" required>
            <div class="underline"></div>
            <label>Ime i Prezime</label>
          </div>

          <div class="input-data">
            <input type="email" name="Email" required>
            <div class="underline"></div>
            <label>Email adresa</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="input-data">
            <input type="text" name="Ime u igrici" required>
            <div class="underline"></div>
            <label>Brawl stars username</label>
          </div>

          <div class="input-data">
            <input type="text" name="TIktok username" required>
            <div class="underline"></div>
            <label>Tiktok username</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="input-data textarea">
            <textarea rows="8" cols="80" name="Poruka" required></textarea>
            <br>
            <div class="underline"></div>
            <label>Zasto kupujes ovaj proizvod iz shopa?</label>
            <h6>>Ukoliko ti je potrebna pomoc mozes da nam pises na:
              <a href="mailto: shop@tutz.info" target="_blank">shop@tutz.info</a></h6>

            <div class="form-row submit-btn">
              <div class="input-data">
                <div class="inner"></div>
                <input type="submit" value="Posalji">
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="Nova porudzbina: battlepass!">
            <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://tutz.info/hvala.html">
            <input type="hidden" name="_template" value="table">
            <input type="hidden" name="_blacklist" value="spammy pattern, banned term, phrase">

          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- This is popout where value need to implement -->

<div class="portfolio-popup">
  <div class="pp-inner">
    <div class="pp-content">

      <div class="pp-header">
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
        <p style="color: red; text-align: center; font-weight: 700">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-triangle-exclamation fa-beat-fade" style="color:red"></i> Slanje forme bez dovoljno poena ce biti kaznjeno smanjenjem poena
          <i class="fa-solid fa-triangle-exclamation fa-beat-fade" style="color:red"></i>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="pp-body">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```